# two levels spatial regression in r

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis, spatial, generalized-estimating-equations

I need help to find the proper approach in R for an analysis of data. I have measures of a variable `Y` for various individuals, distributed in various geographical zones.

I want to perform a regression were Y is explained by variables that are defined for each zone, and I would like to account for correlation between zones (something like a Simultaneous Autoregressive Model, but with repeated measures inside each zone). I don't really know how to proceed:

- summarizing my variable inside each zone, by the mean or median, and use a standard SAM model. But one looses info about variability or amount of measures in each zone, etc. Which seems wrong.
- using the package `spdep` and perform a standard SAM model with repeated measures inside each zone, but in this case I don't know how to account for the fact that the measures are repeated in each zone.
- Using `geeglm` from `geepack` with the zone as cluster and a fixed correlation structure would account for the fact that measures are repeated inside the zone, but I don't know how to include the between zone correlation, needed for spatial analysis
- A mixed effect model, but I do not know how to specify it. Usually, the dependent variable Y vary inside each cluster, and the second level account for variation between cluster. But here I am interested in explanatory variable that are constant inside each cluster and only vary between cluster

Does anyone know what is the proper approach for this situation ?